# How to get P elements until next H2 element via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML structure:

```
<h2>title 1</h2>
<p>bla</p>
<p>bla</p>
<h2>title 2</h2>
<p>bla</p>
<p>blabla</p>
<p>bla</p>
<h2>title 3</h2>
<p>bla</p>
```

The number of P elements after a H2 is various.

The `H2` and `P` elements are a group of elments what I looking for. Is there any solution to get this group of elements or any other way to find P all elements between H2 (or the end of document)?

I was checked `.nextAll()` function, but it found all the next P elements, not until next H2.

Comment: There's a `.nextUntil()` function. Did you checked that?

Comment: Once you've found the relevant elements, what do you want to do with them? Incidentally: [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).

Comment: Is ther only paragraphs in between the h2 elements?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: yes, only paragraps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get each group of the `p` elements in between the `h2` elements or the end, use this:

```
var $h2 = $("h2"); // get the h2 elements
$h2.each(function() { // for each one of them ...
    var $p = $(this).nextUntil("h2", "p"); // get the p elements untill the next h2 element or the end

    // do stuff with this group of p elements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
var set = $('h2').map(function() {
   return $(this).add( $(this).nextUntil('h2') );
});
```

The above answer assumes that there are only `p` elements after each `h2` elements and it create a jQuery collection of jQuery collections. If it doesn't do what exactly you want (by not getting only `p` elements), then you need filter the next elements until the next `h2` element by using a different logic:

```
return $(this).add( $(this).nextUntil('h2').filter('p') );
```